# Amazon Trading API

Tags: api, amazon-web-services

I have used Ebay trading API to get specific seller's

- items
- item transactions (orders)

I am looking forward to implement something similar with Amazon API. But Amazon API procedure looks a bit complicated. Moreover I haven't even got success in finding any API documents to check the functionality of different Amazon APIs.

So, I am looking forward to any kind of help in this matter, any online document or anything else.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Orders API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders/2013-09-01/index.html) might be what you want.  If you have the `AmazonOrderId`, you can submit the `GetOrder` operation to return details about that particular order.  As a starting point, you can use Amazon's [client libraries](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/183-0501338-1361318?ie=UTF8&group=orders&section=orders&version=latest), which are in PHP, C#, or Java.  Typically, I've downloaded the C# library, plugged in my account information and gotten results immediately.  Then I use that knowledge to write my own apps.

There is also the [scratchpad tool](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html) which is great to test all of the various API operations right inside the browser.